# Layout Issues When I Expand The Width Of My Browser

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com

When the device width is greater than 601px I want the following to happen

1. I don't want there to ever be any space between the menu and the
   custom header
2. I don't want there to ever be any space above the customer header. I have now resolved this problem, look here for the solution [Reducing White Space Above Your Header Image Regardless Of The Browser Size](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44555004/reducing-white-space-above-your-header-image-regardless-of-the-browser-size/44555232#44555232).
3. I don't want H1, the plugins or any other content on the page to ever overlap the customer header. I have now resolved this by using code I discuss in the 'Reducing White Space Above Your Header Image Regardless Of the Browser Size' link.
4. I don't want there to ever be any white space to the left or right of the customer header. I have now resolved this problem, look here for the solution [Increasing The Width Of Your Header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44605554/increasing-the-width-of-your-header?noredirect=1#comment76198343_44605554).
5. I want to always be able to see the whole text 'Ross The Explorer', I don't want the last R to ever be removed. I have now resolved this problem using code discuss in the 'Increasing The Width Of Your Header' link.
6. The Navigation Menu bar is always the full length of the page.

Look at www.nomadicmatt.com for an idea on what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you are loading the required Bootstrap CSS and JS properly.

Loading `http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/themes/penscratch/css/bootstrap-3.3.7.css` results in a 404 error (not found), and `http://www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/themes/penscratch/js/bootstrap.min.js` does as well.

So find your enqueue functions that look like this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/bootstrap-3.3.7.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
```

And change them to:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'bootstrap_css', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap_js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js' );
```

Comment: Please see the bottom of my question. I have now edited it based on your response.

Comment: @RossSymonds that is because you are no longer trying to load those urls. As you didn't have those files in the correct place on your server, the code I gave you above loads the bootstrap files from the maxcdn server instead. So when using my code, try adding some bootstrap html, such as a button and see if it works - `<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>`

Comment: Where would I add the code <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>?

Comment: @RossSymonds somewhere visible in the body - doesn't really matter where

Answer (score 0):

You refer to the bootstrap-3.3.7.css in your head but this file doesn't exist on your server/at this address.
You could use a CDN to load boostrap css and js so you won't have to bother having those files on your server, just add these two tags within the head tag:

**CSS:**

```
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

**JS:**

```
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: The reason why your custom header is not showing is because you use percentage to define it's height, but there is not container to refer to. If you use pixel or any other non-relative units, your custom header will show up. 
For example, edit the CSS code you gave us in your first post, and instead of `height:40%` set it to `height:500px`.

It's far from perfect but should put you in the right direction.

Also, if you use my solution, in order to get rid of the 404 errors, remove this code you added in the function.php.
`wp_enqueue_style ...`
and 
`wp_enqueue_script ...`.

Comment: @RossSymonds in order to make it look nicer, take your `<div class="custom-header"></div>` out of its parents div (the col-sm-12 and row). You don't need a to create a row or to use the column system here, your custom header has an absolute position - relative to your page itself.

Comment: I have now attempted to put the custom header in a container but have still not managed to resolve the problem.

Comment: I have now removed col-sm-12.