# Increasing The Width Of Your Header

Tags: php, css, wordpress, header

My website is www.rosstheexplorer.com

I want the header image to stretch across the whole page but I do not want any letters to be chopped off the 'Ross The Explorer' text.

In customer-header.php I had this code

```
 */
function penscratch_custom_header_setup() {
    add_theme_support( 'custom-header', apply_filters( 'penscratch_custom_header_args', array(
        'default-image'          => '',
        'default-text-color'     => '666666',
        'width'                  => 937,
        'height'                 => 300,
        'flex-height'            => true,
        'wp-head-callback'       => 'penscratch_header_style',
        'admin-head-callback'    => 'penscratch_admin_header_style',
        'admin-preview-callback' => 'penscratch_admin_header_image',
    ) ) );
}
```

I changed

```
 'width'                  => 937,
```

to

```
'width'                  = 100%,
```

This had disastrous consequences which you can read about here [Where Can I Download The Wordpress Penscratch Theme Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44590780/where-can-i-download-the-wordpress-penscratch-theme-files/44590928#44590928) and [Finding custom-header.php in file manage on Wordpress Penscratch theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44571516/finding-custom-header-php-in-file-manage-on-wordpress-penscratch-theme/44571694#44571694).

After 3 days I managed to fix the damage.

I have two header images, one for mobile devices. I have code relating to the header images in header.php and Additional CSS.

In header.php the code is

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'penscratch' ); ?></a>


<img class="header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg">


<img class="mobile-header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Cover-Photo-Mobile-Test.jpg">
```

In additional CSS the code is

```
@media screen and (min-width: 661px) {
    .mobile-header-img {
        display: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
    .header-img {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

I am unsure if I need to make modifications in the php files or in Additional CSS. After my last experiment caused me major problems I am reluctant to do any more experimenting on my own. Could someone provide a bit of guidance?

Based on comments below my code is now as follows

**Additional CSS**

```
@media screen and (min-width: 661px) {
        .mobile-header-img {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
 max-width: none;
        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
        .header-img {
            display: none;
width: 100%;
 max-width: none;
        }
    }
```

**Header.PHP**

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'penscratch' ); ?></a>


<img class="header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg">


<img class="mobile-header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Cover-Photo-Mobile-Test.jpg">


<div id="page" class="hfeed site">
```

This achieves my aims up till the width of the browser is greater than 1300px, then white space starts appearing to the right of the header.

Comment: hi, it is not clear what is your intention. Can you make an image for the end result that you want? Just so I can see what do you want.

Comment: On NomadicMatts site (https://www.nomadicmatt.com/) there is never any white space on either side of the header image and all the text on the header image is always visible. I want to replicate that.

Comment: you should be better off finding a better template which has such a design.

Answer (score 1):

Your images will not expand to the full width of the page, because they are inside a wrapper with a max-width. You could take your images outside of the wrapper (see below). You could also apply `position:absolute` to the images, but that would cause a whole other set of problems.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
  <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'penscratch' ); ?></a>
  <div class="header">
    <img class="header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg">
    <img class="mobile-header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Cover-Photo-Mobile-Test.jpg">
  </div>
    <div id="page" class="hfeed site">
```

You would also have to add this CSS to force the image to expand beyond it's natural size, however this would start to blur the image a bit.

```
.header img {
  max-width: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: How can I take the images outside the wrapper?

Comment: By editing your `header.php` file in the same way I have shown in my answer. The `#page` element is the wrapper. So just move your images and your accessibility `.skip-link` outside and above that div.

Comment: Please see the bottom of my original question. I have now modified it.

Comment: @RossSymonds Changing the CSS alone won't fix your problem. You also need to move your images outside of the wrapper div for that CSS to make any effect. Please read my answer in full.

Comment: I was just slightly unsure about the second half of your response.

Comment: I will try and explain better. All of the images on your website currently have a style of `max-width:100%`. This style prevents an image scaling beyond the actual image size. For example your desktop image is 1302px wide. This means the image would only expand beyond 1302px. Which means the image would not fill the width of monitors that are wider than 1302px. So you need to override that style by applying `max-width:none` and  `width:100%` to the images so they will always will the width of the page.

Comment: So would it be worth making a new header which is 2000px and using that header when the browser is over 1302px?

Comment: No. You just need to make the changes to your `header.php` that I have suggested in my answer and it will work.

Comment: Could you look at the bottom of my original question. Have I put 'max-width:none' in the wrong place?

Comment: I have updated my answer that shows exactly what you need to do. The CSS doesn't need to be in a media query. I have added a `.header` div around the images so they can be easily selected with CSS, so be sure to make that change to your `header.php` file as well.

Answer (score 0):

Using WizardCoder fantastic support and advice I was able to solve the problem.

In Additional CSS my code is now

```
@media screen and (min-width: 661px) {
        .mobile-header-img {
            display: none;

        }
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 660px) {
        .header-img {
            display: none;

        }
    }

.header img {
  max-width: none;
  width: 100%;
}
```

In header.php my code is now

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
    <a class="skip-link screen-reader-text" href="#content"><?php _e( 'Skip to content', 'penscratch' ); ?></a>

<div class="header">
<img class="header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/Cover-Photo-6-2.jpg">


<img class="mobile-header-img" src="https://i2.wp.com/www.rosstheexplorer.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/05/Cover-Photo-Mobile-Test.jpg">

 </div>
<div id="page" class="hfeed site">




<header id="masthead" class="site-header" role="banner">
```